# Bounded PCP NP-Complete Proof

Tags: np-hard

I'm looking for a simple proof that shows that the [Bounded-PCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) problem belongs to NP-Complete as many text books say so. It is clear to me that the problem is decidable but I cannot find any reduction from an NP-Hard problem to this one.

Moreover, the verifying algorithm might go through a series of N indexes which is exponential in comparison to the input size (N) which is logN, so how can this problem be in NP?

Thanks.

Comment: Look here http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.